# Spawn moving objects from border

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to make objects from the Angryball class randomly spawn from the right border and move from right to left outside the screen. The idea is that these ogjects must spawn on random y coordinates from the window's right border (better if i can make them seem like if they were coming from outside the border, but that's another point i will check later) and then move at speed 5 until the reach the opposite border. Once one object gets out, another one is spawned again.
I don't have any error when i run this but it doesn't work as expected :) Can you help me figuring this out?

```
import pygame
import os
import random

size = width, height = 750, 422
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
background_image = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()
bg_image_rect = background_image.get_rect()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.display.set_caption("BallGame")

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x
        self.image_rect.y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.image_rect.y < 321:
            self.facing = 'DOWN'
            self.image_rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and self.image_rect.y > 0:
            self.facing = 'UP'
            self.image_rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.image_rect.x < 649:
            self.facing = 'RIGHT'
            self.image_rect.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.image_rect.x > 0:
            self.facing = 'LEFT'
            self.image_rect.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.facing == "RIGHT":
            surface.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "DOWN":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_down.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        if self.facing == "UP":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_up.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "LEFT":
            surface.blit(self.image,(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))



mob_images = [pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image4.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image5.png").convert_alpha()]
mob_image = random.choice(mob_images)

class Angryball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos_x, pos_y):
        super(Angryball, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = pos_x
        self.rect.y = pos_y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.right = screen.get_rect().width
            self.rect.top = random.randint(0, screen.get_rect().height)
        else:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 422))

ball = Ball()
angryball = Angryball(mob_image, 700, random.randrange(400))
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add(angryball)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("bg_music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)


running = True
while running:
    esc_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if esc_key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    ball.handle_keys()

    sprites.update(screen)
    sprites.draw(screen)

    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect)
    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect.move(bg_image_rect.width, 0))
    bg_image_rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
    if bg_image_rect.right <= 0:
        bg_image_rect.x = 0


    ball.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pygame's [Sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

Let `Angryball` inherit from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and rename `image_rect`  to `rect`.

Give it an `update` function like this:

```
def update(self, screen):
    if self.rect.x <= 0:
        self.rect.right = screen.get_rect().width
        self.rect.top = random.randint(0, screen.get_rect().height)
    else:
        self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
```

Instead of manually blitting it to the screen, use a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```
angryball = Angryball(mob_image, 700, random.randrange(400))
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add(angryball)
```

and in your main loop simply call

```
sprites.update(screen)
sprites.draw(screen)
```

---

Your code does not work because you try to use `angryball_image_rect` in the line before you actually declare it.

Comment: Did everything as suggested but now i got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ballgame.py", line 75, in <module>
    sprites.add(angryball)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 360, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 163, in add_internal
    self.__g[group] = 0
AttributeError: 'Angryball' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'

Comment: @Shuratt make sure Angryball is a subclass of Sprite, and make sure you called `super().__init__()` in the `__init__` function of Angryball.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now i don't have any error but i need to edit the post because it doesn't spawn anything ;)

Comment: It's because you draw the sprites to the screen with `sprites.draw(screen)`, but then immediatly overwrite the entire screen with `background_image`. Just make sure you call `screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect)` and `screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect.move(bg_image_rect.width, 0))` before `sprites.draw(screen)`